# What encryption algorithm does Wordpress currently use?

Tags: wordpress, encryption

All answers I can find suggest encryptions like MD5, suggesting the answers are outdated. What does Wordpress currently use?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't encrypt anything and MD5 is not an encryption algorithm but rather an outdated cryptographic hash function.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sorry, got my phrasing mixed up. Do you know what hash they use?

Comment: To do what? WP defines the `wp_hash` function which uses HMAC-MD5 by default, but can be changed by plugins: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash/

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress uses the caeser cipher encryption method